# Using onclick in React - requires being defined?

Tags: reactjs

How can I get this `onclick` function to work in ReactJS?

```
const Message = (props) => (
    <a onClick={kayako.maximize()} href="javascript:;">
        Button to "kayako.maximize()" chat
    </a>
)
export default Message
```

The script for the live chat is

```
<script>{'(function(d,a){function c(){var b=d.createElement("script");b.async=!0;b.type="text/javascript";b.src=a._settings.messengerUrl;b.crossOrigin="anonymous";var c=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];c.parentNode.insertBefore(b,c)}window.kayako=a;a.readyQueue=[];a.newEmbedCode=!0;a.ready=function(b){a.readyQueue.push(b)};a._settings={apiUrl:"https://bold.kayako.com/api/v1",teamName:"Bold Support",homeTitles:[{"locale":"en-us","translation":"Hello! "},{"locale":"id","translation":""}],homeSubtitles:[{"locale":"en-us","translation":"Welcome to Bold Support. Let's chat — start a new conversation below."},{"locale":"id","translation":""}],messengerUrl:"https://bold.kayakocdn.com/messenger",realtimeUrl:"wss://kre.kayako.net/socket",widgets:{presence:{enabled:true},twitter:{enabled:false,twitterHandle:"3299444720"},articles:{enabled:false,sectionId:11}},styles:{primaryColor:"#F1703F",homeBackground:"-192deg, #40364D 37%, #9B4779 100%",homePattern:"https://assets.kayako.com/messenger/pattern-1--dark.svg",homeTextColor:"#FFFFFF"}};window.attachEvent?window.attachEvent("onload",c):window.addEventListener("load",c,!1)})(document,window.kayako||{});'}</script>
```

But how can I define Kayako so that the chat window opens? Here is an example given by Kayako [- Example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QMoyrz?editors=1000)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `kayako` is an external global variable.
Note react event handler property accepts a function. In your code you evaluated `maximize` immediately and passed the result instead of passing a function to `onClick`.
Try:

```
<a onClick={() => kayako.maximize()}>
```